# SOQL Query -REST API

Tags: soql, rest-api

I would like to know if it is possible to insert or update records using a SOQL query in the REST API. thanks

Answer (score 2):

SOQL is inherently read-only. It cannot be used to update records in any context.

You can manipulate records by sending appropriate HTTP requests to the relevant [REST API resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_records.htm) for adding, updating, and deleting sObjects.